# Linkedin add to profile (in new profile design)

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a Linkedin 'add to profile' button in place for the last months. Linkedin deployed a **new profile design for some users** and the button won't work 
The [documentation](https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/) also changed but it's really poor and does not explain anything about required and optional parameters.

It's also hard for me to debug, since I still have the old profile and all work well.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE JUNE 2020: THIS WORKS AGAIN https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/#header2**

I have had an answer from Linkedin support on this subject : "Please also note, with the new site redesign, the Certification information will not auto-populate for members. Clicking on the button will simply take the member to their Certifications section of their Profile where they'll need to manually enter the information.". I have then  asked if this is temporary or final and was answered "At this time, we're not sure. However, feedback like yours is definitely important and has the potential to influence product changes."

So I guess that the best thing is to write to Linkedin to share that it's an issue : https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum . That the place where I got my answer from

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: I found two blog post talking about this (https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/514064 & https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/511577). Linkedin says: "However, we want you to know we are listening and actively monitor your forum posts for your comments and feedback".   But you can't comment on these post, Thanks Linkedin!

Answer (score 0):

Their answer :
"Great question. With the recent site redesign, the Add To Profile feature will no longer autofill the certification and degree information, but you can add the relevant information directly.

However, we want you to know we are listening and actively monitor your forum posts for your comments and feedback. If you are experiencing any issues with features that are not working properly, please contact us below and we’d be happy to look into this for you! If you’d like to see updates on any features or updates we may have, I encourage you to check out our Blog (blog.linkedin.com) as we will typically post updates there first!

Thanks!"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).